# How to get Django to insert checkbox WITHIN label tags?

Tags: django, forms, html

I want my checkboxes adhere to the following bootstrap design:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
</label>
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this in Django (I have Googled it).

Comment: How are you outputting the form in your template?

Comment: Just regularly via {{form}}. Not as_p or etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like the way Django outputs your fields, you'll have to do it manually in the template.

```
<label class="checkbox" for="{{ form.my_checkbox.id_for_label }}">
    {{ form.my_checkbox }} {{ form.my_checkbox.label }}
</label>
{{ form.my_checkbox.errors }}
```

Comment: inside the label tag you would probably want `{{ form.my_checkbox }} {{ form.my_checkbox.label }}`